# python simple if else structure wrong comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

This is my code

```
for i,val in enumerate(DS3Y_pred_trans):
    if val < 1.5:
        DS3Y_pred_trans[i] = 1
    else:
        DS3Y_pred_trans[i] = 2
```

There are values less than `1.5` in the list, but the out is all `2`s.

What am I missing?

This is the whole code.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
DS3X_train = np.genfromtxt('train.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
print DS3X_train

DS3Y_train = np.genfromtxt('train_labels.csv', dtype=int, delimiter=',' )
print DS3Y_train

DS3X_test = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
print DS3X_test

DS3Y_test = np.genfromtxt('test_labels.csv', dtype=int, delimiter=',' )
print DS3Y_test

DS3X_train_trans = zip(*DS3X_train)

cov_train = np.cov(DS3X_train_trans)
U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(cov_train, full_matrices=True)
u = U[:,:-1]
u_trans = zip(*u)
DS3X_train_reduced = np.dot(u_trans,DS3X_train_trans) 

b = np.ones((3,2000))
b[1:,:] = DS3X_train_reduced
print "\n"
DS3X_train_reduced = b


DS3X_train_reduced_trans = zip(*DS3X_train_reduced)

temp = np.dot(DS3X_train_reduced,DS3X_train_reduced_trans)

try:
    inv_temp = np.linalg.inv(temp)
except np.linalg.LinAlgError:

    pass
else:

    psue_inv = np.dot(inv_temp,DS3X_train_reduced)
    print psue_inv.shape

weight = np.dot(psue_inv,DS3Y_train)
weight_trans = zip(weight)
print weight_trans



DS3X_test_trans = zip(*DS3X_test)
DS3X_test_reduced = np.dot(u_trans,DS3X_test_trans)

b = np.ones((3,400))
b[1:,:] = DS3X_test_reduced
print "\n"
print b
DS3X_test_reduced = b

print DS3X_test_reduced.shape
DS3X_test_reduced_trans = zip(*DS3X_test_reduced)
DS3Y_pred = np.dot(DS3X_test_reduced_trans,weight_trans)
print DS3Y_pred
print DS3Y_pred.shape 

DS3Y_pred_trans = zip(DS3Y_pred)

print repr(DS3Y_pred_trans[0])

for i,val in enumerate(DS3Y_pred_trans):
    if val < 1.5:
        DS3Y_pred_trans[i] = 1
    else:
        DS3Y_pred_trans[i] = 2


print DS3Y_pred
now regression using indicator variable and graph plottings
```

Comment: Could not replicate, using e.g. `DS3Y_pred_trans = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]` this works fine for me. What do you have in `DS3Y_pred_trans `?

Comment: Almost certainly your values are *strings*, not numbers. In Python 2 numbers sort before strings, so `val < 1.5` is then *always going to be false*.

Comment: How can i check if they are strings or numbers? Sorry i am new to python.

Comment: @user2871856: give us the output of `print DS3Y_pred_trans`; strings will be represented as Python string literals, e.g. with quotes.

Comment: @user2871856: or you can look at `repr(DS3Y_pred_trans[0])` to look at just one value. Another way would be to show how you created the list in the first place.

Comment: using repr(DS3Y_pred_trans[0]) what i am getting is   (array([1.8434555]),)

Comment: @user2871856: then you have *numpy arrays* in your list; each element is another list-like object. How did you build this structure?

Comment: yeah i used zip(*array ) to make transpose of DS3X_pred

Comment: @user2871856: a transpose doesn't flatten the structure. It leaves you with a list of columns, each column another list.

Comment: @user2871856: your posted code *doesn't use `*`*. You use *just* `zip(DS3Y_pred)`.

Comment: yeah sorry. for a column matrix using * was giving error.

Comment: @user2871856: but omitting the `*` doesn't magically make it all better. Then you are doing a different operation altogether. I'm sure numpy will have functions that help you transpose in more efficient ways. Numpy is not part of my field of expertise however.

Comment: To OP: further to Martijn's comment [`numpy.ndarray.T`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) or [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) can be used to transpose numpy arrays.

Comment: Instead of DS3Y_pred_trans i used DS3Y_pred for iterations in for loop, and thats working. I know my code is not up to the mark but i have a deadline to submit it. Your comments , if any, to improve it are still welcome. Sorry for the trouble caused.

Answer (score 5):

Your values are *not numbers*. In Python 2 numbers sort before other objects, so when comparing `val` with `1.5`, the comparison is always false.

You probably have *strings*:

```
>>> '1.0' < 1.5
False
>>> 1.0 < 1.5
True
```

If so, convert your values to floats first:

```
for i, val in enumerate(DS3Y_pred_trans):
    if float(val) < 1.5:
        DS3Y_pred_trans[i] = 1
    else:
        DS3Y_pred_trans[i] = 2
```

It could be that you are storing other objects in the list still; you'll need to take a close look at what is actually *in* the list and adjust your code accordingly, *or* fix how the list is created in the first place.

Since you are replacing all values anyway, you could use a list comprehension:

```
DS3Y_pred_trans = [1 if float(val) < 1.5 else 2 for val in DS3Y_pred_trans]
```

Comment: You don't need to provide a bad/wrong answer to get downvoted on SO.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I am quite aware of that; but most people voting usually can motivate why, and if they are willing I'd love to hear that reasoning. Clearly they felt my answer was not helpful in some way.

Comment: According to the newest comment from the OP it seems that we have to compare with `val[0]` (or `val[0][0]`- I couldn't quite see that).

Comment: its giving Type error .. float() argument must be string or a number.

Comment: @user2871856: yes, because you don't have strings. How did you build this list in the first place? Are all your list elements `array` objects? Are they all of length 1 perhaps?

Comment: my DS3Y_pred list is like.. [[1.986798] [1.23770].....]   then i did transpose of it using zip(*DS3Y_pred)

Comment: @user2871856: a transpose still leaves you with nested lists, it doesn't *flatten* it.

Comment: I am added my whole code. Can u tell whats the problem now?

Comment: @user2871856: it is still hard for me to tell what exactly is contained in `DS3Y_pred_trans`. Can you include the output of `print DS3Y_pred_trans[:10]` to give us a sample?

Comment: i am unable to copy from command prompt.Is there a way i can put a snapshot her.?\

Comment: @user2871856: also, in future, you should really have included that sample *from the start* for us to reproduce your issues cleanly. I had to guess based on limited information, and now we end up with this *huge long* back and forth about what exactly you *do* have.

Comment: @user2871856: and your command prompt is *just text*. If you cannot copy and paste, then open a file and write the string to that: `with open("filename.txt") as f: f.write(repr(DS3Y_pred_trans[:10]))` will write a short text file you can open in a text editor.